# Macro that Inserts Page Breaks and Prints Only Visible Area

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet with three distinct sections, and I am working on a macro that dynamically adds page breaks that keep groups of [7] rows intact within one section and looks up values within a column to insert two other page breaks that separates the remaining sections from one another.

The first half of my macro works out great and keeps grouped information together from one page to the other as intended. What trips me up is the second half that adds in page breaks based off values that are otherwise hidden via .Find

The first screen shot illustrates an example where all three sections are toggled on (YAY!)

[image]

The second screen shot illustrates an example where I have toggle a section off and hidden it from view (BOO!):

[image]

Where did I go wrong within my code that still partitions a page two even though that section has been hidden?

```
Sub PrintView()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim rng2 As Range
    Dim NewRng As Range
    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lrow As Long
    
    Set rng1 = Range("A6")
    Set rng2 = Range("A:A").Find("XXX BREAK")
    Set NewRng = Range(rng1.Address & ":" & rng2.Address)
      
    
    With ActiveSheet
      .ResetAllPageBreaks
      
        For Each Cell In NewRng
            If Cell.EntireRow.Hidden = False Then
                i = i + 1
            If i Mod 70 = 0 Then ActiveSheet.HPageBreaks.Add Before:=Cell
            End If
        Next Cell
    End With

    On Error Resume Next
        If Range("E:E").Find("TEXT1").Visible = True Then
            ActiveSheet.HPageBreaks.Add Before:=Range("A:A").Find("XXX BREAK").Offset(-1, 0)
        End If
        
        If Range("E:E").Find("TEXT2").Visible = True Then
            ActiveSheet.HPageBreaks.Add Before:=Range("A:A").Find("YYY BREAK").Offset(-1, 0)
        End If
                
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
  
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .PrintTitleRows = "$1:$5"
        .PrintArea = Range("E6:CV" & lastRow).Rows.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Address
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Avoid using "On Error Resume Next" unless you are certain that a specific error is being intentionally ignored. Is there any runtime error w/o it?

Comment: @taller, when I remove the 'On Error Resume Next' from my code I run into the Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set - I assume because 'TEXT1' is hidden which is why I tried to use an If and .Visible to initially get around it.

I tried inserting the code you had provided in place of the 'On Error' section and it added additional page breaks and left the page I was trying to get rid of within the second screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

- Avoid using "On Error Resume Next" unless you are certain that a specific error is being intentionally ignored.
- `Range("E:E").Find("TEXT1").Visible` raises runtime error 438. The `If` clause is skipped due to `On Error Resume Next` (OERN). Then the next line (add page break) is executed regardless of whether the cell is visible or not.
- Never assume that `Find` will definitely locate the specified cell. Best practice is to check whether the positioning was successful after the search.

```vb
    Dim c As Range, pbCell As Range
    Dim aTxt, aBreak, i as Long
    aTxt = Array("Text1", "Text2")
    aBreak = Array("XXX BREAK", "XXX BREAK")
    For i = Lbound(aTxt) To Ubound(aTxt) 
        Set c = Range("E:E").Find(aTxt(i), , xlValues, xlWhole)
        Set pbCell = Range("A:A").Find(aBreak(i), , xlValues, xlWhole)
        If Not (c Is Nothing Or pbCell Is Nothing) Then
            If Not c.EntireRow.Hidden Then
                ActiveSheet.HPageBreaks.Add Before:=pbCell.Offset(-1, 0)
            End If
        End If
        Set c = Nothing: Set pbCell = Nothing
    Next
```